How can i automate export of all users and status (Active, Suspended, Archived) on GWS and then have the report sent to a list of users
Im trying to automate user reports on my Google workspace account showing their statuses and have the report sent via email to a list of recipients monthly.
I am trying to get all users with their statuses with the below script:
function generateUserReport() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const userReportSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('User Report');
  const shareWithEmails = ['example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com']; // Replace with the email addresses you want to share the report with

  const userResult = [];

  const users = getAllUsers();

  users.forEach(user => {
    let status;
    if (user.suspended == true) {
      status = "suspended";
    } else if (user.archived == true) {
      status = "archived";
    } else {
      status = "active";
    }


    let userItem = {
      "primaryEmail" : user.primaryEmail,
      "status" : status,
      "archived" : user.archived,
      "suspended" : user.suspended,
      "isAdmin" : user.isAdmin
    }
    userResult.push(userItem);
  })
  
  jsonToSheet_(userResult, "User Report");
  //shareSpreadsheet(spreadsheet, shareWithEmails);
  //notifyUsers(spreadsheet, shareWithEmails);
}

function getAllUsers() {
  let users = [];
  let pageToken;
  do {
    const response = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      customer: 'my_customer',
      maxResults: 500,
      orderBy: 'email',
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    users = users.concat(response.users);
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return users;
}


function shareSpreadsheet(spreadsheet, shareWithEmails) {
  shareWithEmails.forEach(email => {
    spreadsheet.addEditor(email);
  });
}

function notifyUsers(spreadsheet, shareWithEmails) {
  const url = spreadsheet.getUrl();
  shareWithEmails.forEach(email => {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: 'Monthly User Account Status Report',
      body: `The user account status report has been generated and shared with you. You can access it here: ${url}`
    });
  });
}

function createMonthlyTrigger() {
  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  triggers.forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === 'generateUserReport') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    }
  });

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('generateUserReport')
    .timeBased()
    .onMonthDay(1) // Adjust the day as needed
    .atHour(9) // Adjust the hour as needed
    .create();
}


However, I get this error message when i run or debug the script (also attached a screenshot of the error message
error message
Execution log
3:35:55 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:37:59 PM  Error
ReferenceError: AdminDirectory is not defined
getAllUsers @ Code.gs:40
generateUserReport  @ Code.gs:8

It might be possible that you have not enabled yet the Directory API. Please check out the official quickstart -> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script

Why would you want to do this? It's very inefficient and very insecure to have snapshots of this data in multiple people's inboxes.
You would be better off creating an Access Role in the Admin Console and granting that role to the list of users you would be sending the email to. Then they would be able to view the data in realtime anytime they want to.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9807615
